# how to install watcher on elasticsearch in windows?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to install watcher on elasticsearch, but when running

```
bin\plugin install file:///path/to/file
```

It says

```
'bin\plugin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried many ways but it does not know plugin at all!

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing examples that state to execute .\bin\plugin, the assumption is that your command prompt's working directory is in the root of your Elasticsearch install.

The two simple ways for you to solve this:

1. Make sure your working directory for your command prompt is set to the root of your install
2. Use the absolute path to the plugin script